# Converting a minimized boolean algebric expression into one that uses exclusively NANDs and NOTs.

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

After creating a truth table of my function, transforming it into a Karnaugh Map and extracting the minimized expression from it, I end up with the following expression:

$$AD+\overline{A}\overline{B}\overline{C}\overline{D}+BC+BD+CD$$

The goal is to find an expression equivelant to the one above so that I can create a circuit utilizing only NAND and NOT gates.

I believe that the way I did this isn't correct so here's my process:

$$AD+BD+\overline{A}\overline{B}\overline{C}\overline{D}+BC+CD$$
Applying a double negation:
$$\overline{\overline{AD+BD}}+\overline{A}\overline{B}\overline{C}\overline{D}+\overline{\overline{BC+CD}}$$
Applying the De Morgan rule:
$$=\overline{\overline{AD}.\overline{BD}}+\overline{A}\overline{B}\overline{C}\overline{D}+\overline{\overline{BC}.\overline{CD}}$$
Simplifying:
$$=\overline{\overline{ABD}}+\overline{\overline{BCD}}+\overline{A}\overline{B}\overline{C}\overline{D} = ABD + BCD + \overline{A}\overline{B}\overline{C}\overline{D}$$
Repeating the steps:
$$=\overline{\overline{ABD+BCD}} + \overline{A}\overline{B}\overline{C}\overline{D} = \overline{\overline{ABD}.\overline{BCD}}+\overline{A}\overline{B}\overline{C}\overline{D}$$
How to continue from here so that in the end there are only ANDs and NOTs?

Comment: Here's a hint: For any OR statement $A + B$, you can use double negation twice to get $\lnot \lnot A + \lnot \lnot B$ and then use De Morgan's rule to get $\lnot (\lnot A \cdot \lnot B)$